# How to fix "no such file found error" in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to perform feature extraction from bytefiles.

While opening the file through

```
with open('byteFiles/'+file,"r") as fp:
    ...
```

I am getting an error "Nosuchfilefound". I have checked that the file exists and even tried putting `r` before bytefiles

```
with open(r'byteFiles/'+file,"r") as fp:
    ...
```

but still I am unable to fix it.

```
with open('byteFiles/'+file,"r") as fp:
    lines=""
    for line in fp:
        a=line.rstrip().split(" ")[1:]
            b=' '.join(a)
            b=b+"\n"
            text_file.write(b)
            fp.close()
            os.remove('byteFiles/'+file)
        text_file.close()
```

I am getting the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'byteFiles/01azqd4InC7m9JpocGv5'

Comment: Put "w" there, write something to the file and see where it gets created.

Comment: Please show us what is `file`